# Substring after last occurrence of a number? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, substring

I need to substring a text from the last occurrence of a number, for example:

if the input is: "Any Address, 182739 typeB"
I want the output to be: "tybeB".

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have no idea how can I susbtring from the last number.

"Any Address, 182739 typeB".substring(STUCKED HERE);

Comment: Add some more example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *regular expression*. Match anything, `.*`, until there are one or more digits, `\\d+`, followed by any amount of whitespace, `\\s*`, and then group the remaining characters `(.+)` - use that expression to replace everything with the captured group. Like,

```
String input = "Any Address, 182739 typeB";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".*\\d+\\s*(.+)", "$1"));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
typeB
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Is regular expressions the better way to work with strings? or I have to use this just in the last case?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. There is no one solution that solves all problems.